# Emulador de Android Studio 2.3.1 no inicia

Tags: android-studio

Tenia Android Studio 2.2 y el emulador funcionaba bien, pero actualicé a la versión 2.3.1 y ahora el emulador no funciona o no inicia. Pruebo con un dispositivo real y la aplicación si se compila y ejecuta normalmente.

Comment: Son demasiadas las razones trata de agregar los mensajes de error que se presentan...........

Comment: El siguiente enlace muestra el error que se me presenta, lo interesante es que alli  se da en la version 2.0 de Android Studio: [Error while waiting for device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675654/error-while-waiting-for-device-time-out-after-300seconds-waiting-for-emulator-t). Sin embargo probe las soluciones planteadas alli y ninguna funcionó para mi caso.

Answer (score 1):

**He hallado una solución a mi problema de que no se ejecutaba el emulador de Android Studio 2.3.1.**

Recordando que el problema comenzó cuando actualicé Android Studio de la versión 2.2.x a la versión 2.3.1, creo que esta solución se puede aplicar en cualquier caso que hagas un cambio de versión o instalación de un parche:

1. Verifica que la versión  de Android que vas a correr en el emulador sea de un número entre (o incluidos) **minSdkVersion** y **targetSdkVersion** (Ver archivo build.gradle).
2. Al crear el dispositivo virtual (en el AVD Manager) descarga e instala la versión de Android que le corresponde y asegúrate de que la versión incluya la google API.
3. Para finalizar la creación del dispositivo virtual verifica en opciones de configuración avanzadas del hardware que el parámetro Graphics esté fijado como Software -  GLS 2.0 y que la memoria RAM sea establecida en un número apropiado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Lo más importante (y fue el error que yo noté): en el SDK Manager verifica que la versión de Android que descargaste estén instalados la Google  API y la Intel x86 Atom System Image.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si falta alguna debes descargarla e instalarla.
Así fue como resolví el problema que consistía en que el emulador no se ejecutaba. Todo esto lo debes hacer con cada versión de Android y dispositivo virtual que quieras correr en el emulador.

Espero que esta información les sea de ayuda a quienes se les presente este problema.No he hecho pruebas exhaustivas así que todavía no se me han presentado efectos secundarios o fallas al usar el emulador.